# How do I solve this for zero?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I need to find the solutions to $2x^3-3x^2-12x+3=0$ exactly in order to graph the $x$-intercepts. I can't determine any way to factor them that doesn't involve imaginary numbers. Please help, how should I approach this?

Comment: There are three real roots, you could use numerical methods as it does not factor over integers. You can [*plot*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2x%5E3%E2%88%923x%5E2%E2%88%9212x%2B3) using WA to see approximate location.

Comment: According to [Wolfie](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%5E3+-3x%5E2+-12x+%2B3%3D0) (WolframAlpha), all roots are approximate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the rational root theorem, if there is a rational root, it will be of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ will be a factor of $3$ (the constant term) and $q$ will be a factor of $2$ (the leading coefficient).  So the factors of $3$ are $\pm1$, and $\pm3$ and the factors of 2 are $\pm1$ and $\pm2$.  Therefore if there is a rational root it will be either $\pm1, \pm3, \pm\frac1{2},$ or $\pm\frac3{2}$.  Plug them in and see if they work.

Hint, it is a cubic so it will have at least 1 real root.....why?  Think of the end behavior of the cubic as $x$ tends toward $\pm\infty$.

Also, complex roots come in pairs, and so do irrational roots, so you must have one rational root.....

Finally, once you find the rational root, you will have a quadratic factor left.  By the quadratic formula, you can determine whether there are real or complex roots by the discriminant.  If $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\ge0$, then you will have real roots.  If $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\lt0$ you will have complex roots.